# Using arrays to find a maximum

Tags: c++

I take in an array I go through all it's elements, if any member of the array is greater than j, than it makes that element the new j. For some reason I keep getting back that the maximum is 4. What's going on?

```
##include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int MAXIM(int arg[],int sz){
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
        if(arg[i] > j){
            j = i;
        }
    }
    return j;
}

int main(){

    int coolarr[5] = {5,17,45,7,34};
    int maxxy = MAXIM(coolarr, 5);
    cout << maxxy << endl;
}
```

Comment: When you don't see the error, it is time to start debugging **with a debugger**.

Answer (score 7):

`j = i;` this line is wrong; it should be `j = arg[i];`.